# Operating-System-Level Changes To Speed Up Python's Multiprocessing?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

On the linux system I'm using, the scheduler is not very generous giving cpu time to subprocesses spawned from python's multiprocessing module. When using 4 subprocceses on a 4-core machine, I get around 22% CPU according to `ps`. However, if the subprocesses are child processes of the shell, and not the python program, it goes up to near 100% CPU. But multiprocessing is a much nicer interface than manually splitting my data, and running separate python programs for each split, and it would be nice to get the best of both worlds (code organization and high CPU utilization). I tried setting the processes' niceness to -20, but that didn't help.

I'm wondering whether recompiling the linux kernel with some option would help the scheduler give more CPU time to python multiprocessing workers. Maybe there is a relevant configuration option?

The exact version I'm using is:

```
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 3.19.0-39-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 2 10:00:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

In case this might be related to the way I'm using multiprocessing, it is of the form:

```
 with Pool(4) as p:
     p.map(function,data)
```

Update:
   This is not a reproducible problem. The results reported here were from a few days ago, and I ran the test again and the multiprocessing processes were as fast as I hoped for. Maybe this question should get deleted, it wouldn't be good to mislead people about the performance to expect of `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Are you sure it is the kernel to blame? This issue seems more related to Python being unable to run the jobs truly in parallel.

Comment: The multiprocessing workers are their own processes with their own PIDs. It's my understanding that makes the processes as distinct from each other as they are from, say, my web browser.

Comment: You could [easily] be saturating your memory bus (i.e.) you're memory bound, not compute bound.  Maybe, you could estimate or benchmark to confirm. Look at /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq and set to "performance"

Comment: I think you should write a simple benchmark where each task is completely independent of the others. Then compare running them using the `multiprocessing` module versus starting four instances of a Python script.

Comment: That is what I did and described in my post: "However, if the subprocesses are child processes of the shell, and not the python program, it goes up to near 100% CPU ... manually splitting my data, and running separate python programs for each split".

Comment: If it's speed you're looking for, don't blame the OS. Start writing C++ and enjoy the speed.

Comment: @seewalker I don't believe your tests. Can you repeat the obervation using the benchmark posted in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe your benchmarks are executing as independent tasks as you might think they do. You didn't show the code of `function` but I suspect it does some synchronization.

I wrote the following benchmark. If I run the script with either the `--fork` or the `--mp` option, I always get 400 % CPU utilization (on my quad core machine) and comparable overall execution time of about 18 seconds.  If called with the `--threads` option, however, the program effectively runs sequentially, achieving only about 100 % CPU utilization and taking a minute to complete for the reason [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278955/operating-system-level-changes-to-speed-up-pythons-multiprocessing/34279460#34279460) by [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/450609/dave).

```
import multiprocessing
import os
import random
import sys
import threading


def find_lucky_number(x):
    prng = random.Random()
    prng.seed(x)
    for i in range(100000000):
        prng.random()
    return prng.randint(0, 100)

def with_threading(inputs):
    callback = lambda x : print(find_lucky_number(x))
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=callback, args=(x,)) for x in inputs]
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

def with_multiprocessing(inputs):
    with multiprocessing.Pool(len(inputs)) as pool:
        for y in pool.map(find_lucky_number, inputs):
            print(y)

def with_forking(inputs):
    pids = list()
    for x in inputs:
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            print(find_lucky_number(x))
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            pids.append(pid)
    for pid in pids:
        os.waitpid(pid, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    if sys.argv[1] == '--threads':
        with_threading(inputs)
    if sys.argv[1] == '--mp':
        with_multiprocessing(inputs)
    elif sys.argv[1] == '--fork':
        with_forking(inputs)
    else:
        print("What should I do?", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: What I did is very much like your with_multiprocessing function: starting the processes in a `with Pool` context, and no synchronization or shared memory. The results I reported were what happened several days ago, and I tried running it again, and the results are more like what you found. I'm thinking of deleting the question, because it is not a reproducible problem. Maybe a moderator knows whether it's worth having this up, given that you've made some good points.

Comment: @seewalker I don't know what is the best solution in this case. None of us can delete the question as it is now. I don't know if flagging is appropriate but it is an option. On the other hand, you could try to re-word your question to ask “How to make Python utilize all CPUs?”. But take care not to ask something that is immediately closed as a duplicate.

Comment: I'd leave the question up, in part because of @5gon12eder answer. His test program makes it worth it. And, I'm a longtime programmer, but python newbie, so I got something out of it. But, I've had similar issues with perl WRT splitting using threads or processes.  Even if it's non-reproducible, both the question and answer are clear [and upvoted].  I've seen plenty of questions left up that an OP retries and gets different results. You edited the question with disclaimer--you're covered [legally and morally]. IMO, moderators have bigger fish to fry and no harm, no foul here.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the CPython Global Interpreter Lock.  Your threads show up as distinct processes to the linux kernel (that is how threads are implemented in Linux in general: each thread gets its own process so the kernel can schedule them).

So why isn't Linux scheduling more than one of them to run at a time (that is why your 4 core machine is averaging around 25% minus a bit of overhead)?  The python interpreter is holding a lock while interpreting each thread, thus blocking the other threads from running (so they can't be scheduled).

To get around this you can either:

1. Use processes rather than threads (as you mention in your question)
2. Use a different python interpreter that doesn't have a Global Interpreter Lock.

Comment: In all respect, I don't think that this is the correct answer. The first paragraph of the documentation says: *`multiprocessing` is a package that supports spawning processes using an API similar to the `threading` module. The `multiprocessing` package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads.*

Comment: Yes, it was maybe premature of me to mark that as the correct answer. The particular case I was running into was probably Global Interpreter Lock related (thanks dave!), but thank you for noticing that multiprocessing is not deeply tied to that lock.